# Instabug instance is never destroyed [Android]

Tags: android, instabug

In my `onCreate` method, I've initialized `Instabug` following the steps on the official docs. If I invoke `Instabug`, it is never destroyed, even after my app is. The dialog appears and whether or not I submit a bug, I can see a separate `Instabug` activity exists on my phone's activity stack. If I close out my application, the `Instabug` instance still exists. How can I destroy the `Instabug` instance?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to read more about **[Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)**.

What happened, that you started the *Instabug* functionalities at the beginning of your app launch.
When you click the home-page button, it put your app to the *recent apps* (Running in the background), thus, the *Instabug* functionality still exist and running [Until you remove the app from recent app of-course].

So, You need to [`disable()`](https://www.instabug.com/public/android-api-reference/com/instabug/library/Instabug.html#disable--) your app *Instabug* functionality once needed, and [`enable()`](https://www.instabug.com/public/android-api-reference/com/instabug/library/Instabug.html#enable--) it again if needed.